# What is an xtree is Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, tree, structure

I'm learning about the various data structures and templates available in C++. While include the header for vectors, I came across a header called xtree. I can't find any documentation on this header file from Microsoft (using VS10). My question is what exactly is this header used for and what does it contain? Is it even a data structure? Is it an obsolete header? An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, it contains helper stuff used for implementing `std::set` and `std::map`, which have (this is the only sane way to achieve the required big-O performance characteristics and provide the required functionality) a tree structure internally. I can't guess why `<vector>` would need it - were you just browsing around in the folder?

Comment: Correct, and to be specific, it's a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) implementation.

Comment: Cool. GCC uses a red-black tree as well, as indicated by internal type names like 'rbtree_iter'. I wonder why they taught us about AVL trees instead in university :/

Comment: Yeah, I enjoy learning about the various templates and structures used in programming. When using the keyword #include <, a list of headers pop up in VS, and I saw xtree not too far from vector.